# Where does the linker get library names?

Tags: c++, linker, autotools

I'm kind of new to developing, and I am wondering how the linker is getting the library names?
for example, in the linker additions lines, when i wanted to add support for libxml2, the command was -lxml2. yet when i wanted to add the lib for xmlsec, it was -lxmlsec1. when i wanted to add openssl, i needed both a -lcrypto and a -lssl.
can someone explain to me where these library names come from? it doesn't seem very intuitive. if i want to include a library, how am i supposed to find what -l command to use?
this is on a ubuntu system developing a C++ program.

Comment: Library names are arbitrary. The documentation tells you what to use.

Comment: Your question is confusing. It seems like you really want to know where the **programmer** gets library names. The linker gets them from the `-l` options, which you seem to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'regular' linker is dumbest program I know of :) When it comes for libraries, it follows a very simple set of rules. First, for every -l rule it adds lib in front and .a in the end to form a static library name. It also forms a dynamic library name by adding .so instead of .a. For every -I rule it adds specified path to it's library search paths.

So when it sees a -l rule, and looks into all library paths which were set by -L rules (in the order those appeared in the command line) and sees if it can find dynamic or static library at this location (if it can see both, it picks one depending on -B rule).

This was a generic introduction. Now, to your particular question, in order to check which library you should include, you should read documentation. I always tells you which -l rules you'd need.

Comment: There are tools to resolve necessary linker flags on most linux distros. The li linker itself isn't _dumb_, just provide it with the right information!